# How to import nested local file

Tags: go, buffalo

Before:

```
actions
├── app.go
├── upload_sessions.go
├── upload_sessions_test.go
```

What I want to change it to:

```
actions
├── app.go
├── v2
│   ├── upload_sessions.go
│   └── upload_sessions_test.go
```

When I try nesting the upload_sessions.go file in the `v2/` folder and adding this import:

```
import ("actions/v2")
```

1) my go formatter in VIM deletes it (since it is unused), and 2) the compiler errors in `app.go` with:

```
uploadSessionResource := UploadSessionResource{} // this causes a compiler error: actions/app.go:80:28: undefined: UploadSessionResource
```

What do I need to do to import a local file in Go / Buffalo?

Comment: You need to include which package the type is defined in e.g. `v2.UploadSessionResource{}`.

Comment: I tried buy goimports was deleting it. What would the import look like?

Comment: It's deleting it because you're not preceding the package's type with the package name. Notice the `v2.` before `UploadSessionResource{}`.

Comment: Though, you may be having problems because of the package's name. You can also try aliasing the package when importing e.g. `import "actions/v2" actions` and then use `actions.UploadSessionResource{}`.